# Polymer 1.0 reading select value when there is an inside template(dom-repeat) in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

i'm having trouble with a polymer 1.0 element.
I have to print inside a select every option of a book size (A5, A4) and the extra prices for every selection(this information is from an js array returned from _returnSelItemDataArr).
The array data looks something like this:
[image]

```
_returnSelItemDataArr: [array[id, name, extra], array[id, name, extra]].
```

Here is a bit of source code :

```
    <select id="sizeSelect" value="{{itm.id::change}}" aria-labelledby="sizeLabel">
                                            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_returnSelItemDataArr(item, 'sizes')}}" as="itm">
                                                <option value="{{index}}" selected$="[[_computeSelected(index, itm)]]">{{itm.name}} (+{{itm.extra}} lei)</option>
                                            </template>
        </select>


Select compute function:


    _computeSelected: function(index, itm) {
             return index+1===parseInt(itm.id, 10);
          },
```

The problem is when i try to get the selection value from "#sizeSelect" by this code : `this.$.sizeSelect.value` the console output of select value is `undefined` .
Accesing the select value seems to be a problem when using polymer with dom-repeat for options.
Anyone happens to know how to access the select value properly ?
**NOTE: I have to mention that 'item' is my product, it's an object that contains all the information about the product**
**Answer:**
To select an element by id under shadow-dom you will have to use this operator `$$` . For me was something like this: `this.$$('#sizeSelect').value`.

Comment: What are your declared properties? Your bindings looked confused as `itm` is used as a binding in both `select` and `dom-repeat`. Call the value of `select` something else like `sizeIndex`.

Comment: Why do you have `Array` inside `Array` why not `Object` inside `Array`? And the reason why its not working is `itm`'s scope is only inside the `dom-repeat` template outside that `itm`is undefined.

Comment: I solved the problem by doying this select query that was retrieving the correct value of the selection : `this.$$('#sizeSelect').value` . I didn't know that i have to use `$$` if i am selecting something under `shadow-dom` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
To select an element by id under shadow-dom you will have to use this operator `$$` . For me was something like this: `this.$$('#sizeSelect').value`.